# JQuery function syntax

Tags: jquery

Is it okay to use a click function within a click function like so? I need to have the bookId and then use it in the function below.

```
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');

    $(".valo").on('click', function(){
      // something
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain the desired behavior more?

Comment: Sure. The user will click a link to open a modal window. Inside that modal will be an accordion with checkboxes. I need to know what checkbox was checked along with the modal-id. I need to have both values together in order to complete the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NaN thanks for the clarification.  Given your usecase- there is absolutely nothing wrong with this.

Comment: OK, thank you Derek. I'll accept when the 6 minute timer expires. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's perfectly fine and valid, whether it's what you want is another question. This will have the, likely unitended, consequence of binding a click event to all '.valo' elements *every single time* you show your modal.

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the best way for me to handle my issue. Maybe you can advise. What I want to do is to use one modal and one accordion for multiple images. The way I'm doing it now, I'm building a modal and accordion for each image. I don't think this is correct though. I should be able to use just one copy of modal/accordion and get the value of the image that was clicked and use it along with the checked value inside the accordion. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm afraid without more context this is going to be too difficult to give reasoned advice. Perhaps you can create another question more closely targeted to where you're struggling and provide further code samples. In the mean time, in order to see what I was getting at in my answer try adding a js alert within your on click function of '.valo' then open/close several modals and click on a .valo element. You'll see you keep getting an additional alert for every modal open event that occurs. Best of luck with your project :)

Comment: `.one()` does not prevent multiple binding instances. It simply means that the event will only be fired once.

Comment: @linuscash, yeah, I see what you mean now. I still have an issue with this. I'm not getting the result I expect. I'll post another question with a little more context and code in a bit. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Terry is right by the way. `.one()` is not intended to prevent multiple bindings that was a bad call on my part in referencing that as it does not solve the issue I was highlighting. I'll edit to remove the suggestion.